# Как сохранить ключ после закрытия activity при шифровании

Tags: java, android, криптография

```
      Encryption encryption = Encryption.getDefault("Key", "Salt", new byte[16]);

encrypted = encryption.encryptOrNull(encrypted);
 decrypted = encryption.decryptOrNull(encrypted);
```

Так не получается

сохранение

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("key", String.valueOf(encryption));
        editor.apply();
```

загрузка

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        String encryption = (settings.getString("key", ""));
        editor.apply();

        decrypted=encryption;
```

Comment: Храните ключ в переменной и при onDestroy() сохраняйте его а в onCreate() загружаете обратно в переменную. Сохранение и загрузку данных можете делать с помощью sharedpreferences

Comment: Метод onDestroy()  не гарантированый, большинстве случаев вообще вызываться не будет. Лучше на OnPause()

Comment: Попробуйте так Context.MODE_PRIVATE. Ну и settings у вас разумеется одна переменная, а не две?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ключ нельзя сохранять (точка)
2. Если очень хочется сохранить ключ (см. п.1)
3. Если все равно хочется сохранить ключ еще раз посмотрите на п.1

Теперь более серьезно. Используются в общем случае 3 подхода как сохранять ключи (в случае Android)

1)Универсальный подход: ключ генерируется на основе пароля заданного юзером. Берем пароль и на его основе генерируем ключ. Процедура описана в т.н. [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (Password Based Key Generation Function v.2). В коде выглядит примерно так:

```
public static String generateKey(String password, String salt) {
        char[] chars = password.toCharArray();
        byte[] salt = salt.getBytes();

        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(chars, salt, 1010101,
                20 * Byte.SIZE);
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        byte[] hash = skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();

        return toHex(salt) + ":" + toHex(hash);
}
```

То есть ничего не храним. Юзер задает пароль из пароля генерируем ключ и шифруем/дешифруем. Если ключ не подошел - ну извините.

2)В качестве пароля используем уникальный идентификатор устройства [ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID) - обратите внимание:

> 64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string), unique to each combination of app-signing key, user, and device. Values of ANDROID_ID are scoped by signing key and user.

то есть идентификатор генерируется для конкретного устройства и конкретного приложения + юзера устройства. То есть на другом приложении он будет другой. При хард ресете устройства он генерируется заново (что иногда может стать проблемой).

3)Используем [Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) - по сути криптографически защищенное устройство для хранения данных. Проблема в том, что некоторые Android девайсы предоставляют заведомо ущербные софтверные реализации. Настоящая реализация должна поддерживать т.н. TEE (Trusted Execution Environment) - защищенная среда исполнения (как правило, в виде специального чипа/процессора, внутри которого проводятся крипто-операции) - например [Samsung KNOX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Knox) или Titan M в Google Pixel. Проверить наличие хардверной реализации можно примерно так:

```
PrivateKey key = ...; // Android KeyStore key
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm(), "AndroidKeyStore");
KeyInfo keyInfo = factory.getKeySpec(key, KeyInfo.class);
boolean isHardwareBacked = keyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware();
```